# Google Pay PHP integration explanation

Tags: integration, google-pay

I want to integrate Google payments with my online shop and I am looking for any examples how to do it with PHP. I have already used javascript one and it was pretty simple. I was wondering what happens when the payment is being processed, can it communicate with my server in order to save the data? As far as I know the client side implementation is only doing the payment, correct me if I am wrong. I hope you can share a link to documentation explaining it.

Comment: Google Pay doesn't process the payment, it facilitates the payment by working with a payment processor to securely negotiate a payment token. Is your payment processor listed on the following page? https://developers.google.com/pay/api/

Comment: @Soc I decided to go for Stripe, seems to be easy to use, if that's what you call a processor

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. Out of interest, which integration did you choose? Stripe Elements (payment request button) or did you go directly with the Google Pay button?

Comment: @Soc I used apple pay / google pay button (payment request button), because apple pay was my priority for this specific shop